# looping through Two menus and displaying outputs based on prompt

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

when the script starts it list a menu from files in a directory and prompt for selection, when a file is selected, another menu is displayed with what user wants to do,now the user wants to use option 6 to return to the previous menu which is done successfully but the script doesn't seem to update when the user chooses another option from the main menu :

```
#!/bin/bash


echo "Welcome to Led_Config"
echo "============================"

echo "Please select a led to configure"

echo "---------------------------------"

print_menu(){
i=({0..7})

for file in /sys/class/leds/* 
do 
    echo ${i[i++]}".""$(basename "$file")"

done

echo ${i[7]}".""Quit"
echo "------------------------------------"
printf "Please enter a number (1-8) for the led to configure or quit:"
read ans
clear
}
print_menu


while [ $ans != '' ]
do
    if [[ $ans = 5 ]]
    then 
    echo "LED0"
    echo "====="
    PS3="Please enter a number (1-6) for your choice:"
    options=("turn on" "turn off" "associate with a system event" \
        "associate with the performance of a process" \
        "stop association with a process performance" \
        "quit to main menu")
    select opt in "${options[@]}"
    do
    case $REPLY in 
        1) echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness;;
        2) echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness;;
        3) echo "Associate Led with a System Event";
            echo "============================";
            echo "Available Events are:";
            echo "---------------------";
            i=({0..34})
            for file in /sys/class/leds/led0/*
            do 
                echo ${i[i++]}".""$(basename "$file")"
            done;;
        6) print_menu;
    esac 
done    




elif [[ $ans = 6 ]]
then
    echo "LED1"
    echo "===="
     PS3="Please enter a number (1-6) for your choice:"
     options=("turn on" "turn off" "associate with a system event" \
                  "associate with the performance of a process" \
          "stop association with a process performance" \
                  "quit to main menu")
     select opt in "${options[@]}"
     do
     case $REPLY in 
                                                         1) echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led1/brightness;;      2) echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led1/brightness;;
         6) print_menu;;

             esac 
     done            
 fi


if [[ $ans = 7 ]]
then
    exit
else 

    echo "under construction"
    break
fi
done
```